# How to send form-data as text using Rest Assured

Tags: rest-assured, rest

how do I send form-data as 'Text' via Rest Assured, please refer to the screenshot.  When I use request.multipart("key"."value") request is being sent as file( refer screenshot ). TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send `form-data` parameter with Rest Assured, you can use the `param` function of Rest Assured:

```
 given()
        .param("key", "value")    
        .post("your_api_url");
```